# store values in php array/session by ajax in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to store values in PHP array or PHP session by ajax in jquery 
I'm sending some values by ajax on a php page and want to store them

Problem : Every time array/session return the latest sent value , not the previous values that i sent
i  want that previous sent values should retain in array or session

my code is Below

Js File Code

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://domain.com/ajax.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: { name : nname , 
                    clas : nclass , 
                    rows : nrows ,
                    cols : ncols , 
                    types : ntype , 
                    check : ncheck , 
                    count : ncldiv
                 },

            success: function(data){
             alert(data); 
           }
            });
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();    
        $type = $_POST['types'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $class = $_POST['clas'];
        $rows = $_POST['rows'];
        $cols = $_POST['cols'];
        $check = $_POST['check'];
        $count = $_POST['count'];
         $output_string = array('TYPE'=>$type,'NAME'=>$name,'CLASS'=>$class,'ROWS'=>$rows,'COLS'=>$cols,'REQUIRED'=>$check);
        array_push($_SESSION['feilds'] , $output_string );
        print_r($_SESSION['feilds']);
?>
```

Comment: it will override the previously stored value in session. because you are overwriting values using same key

Comment: because you `$_SESSION['feilds']=array()` deletes previous array and creates an new empty array, where you push new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you instantiate the `$_SESSION['feilds']` variable as blank array always. Use this:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['feilds'])) {
        $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();
    }
    $type = $_POST['types'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $class = $_POST['clas'];
    $rows = $_POST['rows'];
    $cols = $_POST['cols'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
     $output_string = array('TYPE'=>$type,'NAME'=>$name,'CLASS'=>$class,'ROWS'=>$rows,'COLS'=>$cols,'REQUIRED'=>$check);
    array_push($_SESSION['feilds'] , $output_string );
    print_r($_SESSION['feilds']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to `$_SESSION['feilds'] = array();`.

When page is called `$_SESSION['feilds']` is assign blank array.That is why you only get current value.

Check `$_SESSION['feilds']` is already exists or not by using `isset` or `empty`

```
if(empty( $_SESSION['feilds'] )) {
  $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    you wrote  $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();
    Every time it  assign a empty array at session so it will wash out previous data. 
if you want to retain your previous data then first add check like 
        if(empty( $_SESSION['feilds'] )) {
          $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();
        }
        after that you assign value to session as you are doing 
hope it will help you :)
```